# Filtering dictionary entries from imported excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to remove the dictionary entries that are imported as nan (because they are empty in the excel file).

```
import pandas as pd
import pprint
from math import isnan

df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Data.xlsx')
d = df.to_dict()

clean = {k: d[k] for k in d if not isnan(k)}

pprint.pprint(clean)
```

However this is giving me the error

> TypeError: must be real number, not str

If I instead use the following command to filter out nan

`clean = filter(lambda k: not isnan(k), d)`

i do not get an error, but the print command returns

> "filter object at 0x0000021EA45EB4A8"

instead of my dictionary entries

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas to read the excel file into a DataFrame, why not just use `dropna` method?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

You can drop rows or column (`axis` - defaults to rows) where any or all (`how` parameter) entries are NaNs.

Comment: So i did this and it worked, but it dropped all my entries. I went back and looked at why this is happening.

My dictionary is being returned as 

>'INDEX': {0: 249.99,
             1: 599.99,
             2: nan,
             3: nan,
             4: nan,
             5: 129...}

and df.dropna() is turning it into

>'INDEX': {}

Comment: If INDEX was the only column, the default dropna arguments would leave 0, 1 and 5 from your example unless there are NaNs in other columns in the same rows. If you want to only filter the INDEX column, use dropna(subset=['INDEX']).